# Analytical Function for Querys

Tags: sql, oracle, select

### I am working on a scenario for one of my projects at work I don't have any tables or data to fill those tables but I have to write a hypothetical query-

i wrote some of the query with regulaur sql but i think analytical functions come into play for part 2

the database supposedly gets 50 million records of flying cars a day and each record logs the position of a car every second for the entire day

i need to write a query that identifies any speeders speeding lets say will be anything over 500 miles per hour

and then i need to write another query that makes sure cars keep a distance of 50 feet from any other flying car so i have to identify anyone within 50 feet of each other anytime in the day thats airborne [ 50 feet altitude ] etc..

after i also need to write a query to ticket top 5% of speeders, assuming max speed within the city (including highways) is 50mph.
the information i have to write the query with is GPS timestamp, GPS latitude and longitude of camera, and car license plate.

here is what i have so far

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION speed(lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT, t time) RETURNS FLOAT AS $$
DECLARE                                                   
    x float = 69.1 * (lat2 - lat1);                           
    y float = 69.1 * (lon2 - lon1) * cos(lat1 / 57.3);
    d float = sqrt(x * x + y * y);  
    tcon float = extract(hour from t);     
BEGIN
   RETURN d/tcon;
END  
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

insert into report
    values (1,'04:23:20', 40.23,40.78,1200,1);
insert into report
    values(2,'03:21:00', 89.12,-120.56,1300,1);
insert into report
    values(3,'18:16:18', 30.12,-4.56,1400,1);
insert into report
    values (1,'04:56:00', 75.23,152.78,1200,2);
insert into report
    values(2,'06:14:00', 89.12,-12.56,1300,2);
insert into report
    values(3,'19:21:10', 60.12, 15.42,1400,2);
select report.carid,speed ((select(report.lat from report where carid = carid and entrynum = entrynum),
                select(report.lon from report where carid = carid and entrynum = entrynum),
                select(report.lat from report where carid = carid and entrynum = entrynum+1),
                select(report.lon from report where carid = carid and entrynum = entrynum+1),
                select(report.thours from report where carid = carid and entrynum = entrynum+1)
                from report)) as s
```

I dont know what to do next

Comment: i am using data that isnt excatly in a table but making it up to fit the questions need

Comment: Have you looked at Oracle's spacial and geocoding types.  e.g. SDO_GEOMETRY?

Answer (score 0):

I would examine Oracle's Spacial and Geo facilities.  You can get more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_intro.htm)

Comment: not helping me at all i need to write it out more procedurely

Comment: Then trying to solve this in a database engine may not be the way to go.  PL/SQL is a declarative language with procedural extensions, but a declarative language first and foremost.  The facilities for handling geometric and geographical information help solve certain parts of the problem such as identifying the closest objects.  What you are specifying is a very broad problem whose solution will involve a non-trivial amount of code and analysis.  I doubt you will get an answer here that breaks your problem down in that much detail.  That is your job.

Comment: It can be done the other people I work with have done it

Comment: @seeeql, then perhaps you should pose this question to them instead.